# I want help with using fingerprint sensor of elan tech

Tags: 20.04, fingerprint-reader

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

I want use Elan Tech fingerprint sensor on my Asus Vivobook 15 X510Q. I can't enroll fingerprint with the option given in settings. However, when I try, it just says `Failed to enroll new fingerprint`. How can I resolve this issue and use my fingerprint reader?
[image: Error message displaying the text "Failed to enroll new fingerprint"]

I tried `fprintd-enroll` command but it shows enrolling right index finger for a long time but no further result and in settings sensor is shown shown as disabled.
Also, `lsusb` command shows "Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:0903 Elan Microelectronics Corp."

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: Okay waltnator my bad

Comment: @waltinator do you know how to fix this issue

Comment: I'm losing all hope with this whole community thing, might be working for others but not me and up to an extend pure waste of time....